# C++ make an exe unkillble by taskkill /F or taskmanger endprocess

Tags: c++, windows, exe

I'm new to C++ and can somebody please provide me a full code to hide a certain exe?
I know there's something to do with editing the ACL  in windows but I'm not sure about the details.

THANKS!

Comment: Sounds like you wanna implement a virus...

Comment: well... some users are bad right...

Comment: I guess it could be a virus for a good cause...

Comment: Do you have an answer to this by any chance?!?

Comment: No, but I doubt that it has anything to do with C++. It's an OS-related issue (Windows in this case, since you're asking about *exe*).

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not from user mode. You can *hide* your executable in other ways ranging from obfuscation to process hollowing, but you can't prevent it from being killed. The reason is because any other process, even in user mode, has access to open a handle to any other process at or lower than its permission level. What it sounds like you want is [ObRegisterCallbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-obregistercallbacks) from a kernel driver.